# Why Streamlit sharing pyodbc error when deploy?

Tags: python, deployment, cloud, pyodbc, streamlit

I have a simple streamlit app that connects to an SQL server with **pyodbc**.
it's working fine locally but when I try to deploy on streamlit Cloud I have this error:

```
    import pyodbc
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

in my Git I have the **requirement.txt** that contains:

- networkx==3.0
- streamlit==1.11.1
- pyodbc==4.0.30
- pandas==1.0.5
- numpy==1.22.0
- matplotlib==3.2.2

And I have also the **packages.txt** that contains:

- unixodbc-dev

Someone Knows what's wrong in the deployment process?

Thanks!

Comment: I also try with an packages.txt file that contains: "msodbcsql17". But I have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements file should be named "requirements.txt" rather than "requirement.txt"

Answer (score 0):

The connection don't need the file **packages.txt** anymore.

And Make sure to have in the Driver:

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}
```

if you don't want to have the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

For someone who want a tuto clearly explained, go to this link:
[Tuto for connection OBDC on streamlit Cloud](https://github.com/streamlit/docs/pull/315/commits/43a6cc76303bb20430a85d121171f245bd050d15?short_path=f85f758#diff-f85f758c7ead00ddf394867b7b33a317dbd62dd0b449cd8b4df3b135c42ac139)